# Best practise creating a shared method between devise SessionsController and RegistrationsController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

There are 3 ways to get in my applications with an invite token:

- You're already logged in
- You have an account, but not logged in
- You need to register

Now I'm interested how to handle the last 2 situations in combination with `Devise` without having to repeat the same functions.

Controller overrides are handled from the routes.rb:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {
      sessions: 'users/sessions',
      registrations: 'users/registrations'
  }
```

Overriding the `after_sign_in/up_path` for Sessions and Regitrations:

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  protected
  def after_sign_in_path(resource)
    handle_invite
    super(resource)
  end
end
```

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  protected
  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    handle_invite
    super(resource)
  end
end
```

**Where should I place the `handle_invite` method?**

I'm looking for a solution that I can put the method in my `UsersController`, because that seems to be the right place to put it.:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  private
  def handle_invite
    # Some code getting the token and adding the user to a group
  end
end
```

I thought this should work, because it seems that Devise inherits this controller:

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController; end
class Devise::SessionsController < DeviseController; end
class DeviseController < Devise.parent_controller.constantize; end
```

So I expected `Devise.parent_controller.constantize` to represent `UsersController`, but for some reason `handle_invite` can't be called from the child controllers.

Comment: If you had a concern file for your devise methods (e.g. something like `/app/controllers/concerns/devise_invites.rb`), could you possibly just include that concern in the controllers where you need it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use classical inheritance you would have to actually place that class in the inheritance chain by configuring `Devise.parent_controller` while not breaking the rest of the chain.

Ruby does not have multiple inheritance. A class may only inherit from a single parent class.

```
# config/initializers/devise.rb
config.parent_controller = 'UsersController'
```

```
class UsersController < DeviseController
  private
  def handle_invite
    # Some code getting the token and adding the user to a group
  end
end
```

But that's not really the best way to solve it since Ruby has horizontal inheritance through modules:

```
# app/controllers/concerns/invitable.rb
module Invitable
  private

  def handle_invite
    # Some code getting the token and adding the user to a group
  end

  def after_sign_in_path(resource)
    handle_invite
    super(resource)
  end
end
```

```
# Do not use the scope resolution operator (::) for namespace definition!
# See https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#namespace-definition
module Users
  class SessionsController < ::Devise::SessionsController
    include Invitable
  end 
end
```

```
module Users
  class RegistrationsController < ::Devise::SessionsController
    include Invitable
  end 
end
```

This is known as a module mixin. In other languages like Java or PHP it would be called a *trait*. The module encapsulates a set of methods that can be included in any class and you can also mix modules into other modules.

In Rails lingo module mixins are called `concerns` - this really just wraps a convention that the `app/controllers/concerns` and `app/models/concerns` directories are added to the autoload roots. Which means that rails will look for constants in the top level namespace there.

This is also loosely connected to [ActiveSupport::Concern](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html) which is syntactic sugar for [common ruby idioms](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_modules.htm). But there is no need to use it unless you're actually using its features.